# Creating new window using keyboard keys

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5, pynput

I want to create a new window when I click on 'O' key on the keyboard... But when I click 'O' the new widget crashes...

I tried to make a new widget using QPushButton and it worked... But when I use listener the new widget crashes

I know that I may use 'QShortcut' but I use pynput so I can detect whether 'O' is pressed or not even if my pyqt5 app is out of focus..

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.uic import loadUiType

import sys

from pynput import keyboard

class win(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
        # self.setWindowFlag(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)

        self.btn = QPushButton('close', self)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(lambda: self.close())

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle('Student log in screen')
        self.show()




class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setGeometry(500, 500, 500, 400)


        self.start_btn = QPushButton('start', self)
        self.start_btn.clicked.connect(lambda : self.start())

       

    def copy(self):
        pya.hotkey('ctrl', 'c')
        time.sleep(.05)
        return pyperclip.paste()    

    def test(self, key):
   
        try:
            k = key.char  # single-char keys
        except:
            k = key.name  # other keys

        if k == 'o':
            print('you pressed o')
            
            self.widget = win()
            # self.w.show()

    def start(self):
        
        self.listener = keyboard.Listener(on_press=self.test)   
        self.listener.start() 


            


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Main()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: The callback associated with the Listener is executing in a second thread, and you in that callback are creating the widget which is prohibited. It uses the KeyMonitor class (from the answer to the duplicate question) that emits signals preventing the slot from being invoked in the secondary thread but in the thread that the receiver lives.

Comment: is there any unprohibited way to create a secondary widget ??

Comment: No, it is not forbidden to create a second widget but to create a second widget in a secondary thread

Comment: 1. add `self.monitor = KeyMonitor()` `self.monitor.keyPressed.connect(self.test)`  before `self.start_btn = QPushButton('start', self)` 2. change `self.start_btn.clicked.connect(lambda : self.start())` to `self.start_btn.clicked.connect(self.monitor.start_monitoring)`

Comment: it worked thnx eyllanesc